# wordpress find iframe code from post content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have one post that contains some text, images and **iframe** code.  i want to display only iframe code in front side not text or images .

i can fire the select query to fetch the content but that will return the full content of the post.  while i only want to fetch iframe code from the content.

is there any way to do that?  is it possible to filter the content what we are fetching from the database?

how can i check into content for iframe code only ?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by _iframe content_? Content of the website it is pointing to? 2. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try to have your question clearly, as your question is unclear, this is the answer from what i understood

make that iframe inside a div tag and give a 'id' to that div tag

and load that particular div tag using jquery/javascript when needed. . .